# Build a Map with objects that have dependencies

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger

I have an interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {...}
```

Each implementation of MyInterface has its own (different) dependencies. Example:

```
public class MyObjectOne implements MyInterface {
    @Inject ServiceA ...;
    ...
}

public class MyObjectTwo implements MyInterface {
    @Inject ManagerB ...;
    @Inject ProviderC ...;
    ...
}
```

I could have hundreds of MyInterface implementations. Now I want to create a Map as follow:

```
Map<String, MyInterface> map = new HashMap<String, MyInterface>();
map.put("key1", new MyObjectOne());
map.put("key2", new MyObjectTwo());
...
map.put("keyn", new MyObjectN());
```

Unfortunately, this short-circuit Dagger and won't inject anything in MyObjectOne, MyObjectTwo, ... and MyObjectN. Besides, I don't have an ObjectGraph at this point as this code is part of a library/module.

As I was looking for a solution, I came across the [MapBinder](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) class in Guice that seems to do what I want. This feature is not available with Dagger.

1. Can my problem be solved with Dagger?
2. If not, is MapBinder a feature that could make it into Dagger 2.0?

Cheers and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it would be a design-flaw having the need to instantiate something yourself. Dependency Injection was made to elevate that problem and the resulting boiler-plate. I personally would have the classes in a module as `injects` or `includes` and inject the instances (probably singletons) into that map.

In your case, what you want to inject is a `MemberInjector` and inject into the member of `MyObjectOne` etc. With that you can create your own MapBinder easily by iterating over the values of the map.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You said => "I personally would have the classes in a module as injects or includes and inject the instances (probably singletons) into that map."Do you mind developing your idea? Do you mean to have each "MyObjectX" instantiated in a @Provide method. I am not sure I undertand the second part of the comment too.

Comment: You may want to edit your question further to clarify what you actually want to achieve. `MapBinder` for Guice is handled a bit different than in Dagger, since Dagger should be used to verify the `ObjectGraph` in CompileTime, but in Guice is all RunTime.

Even if you dont actually use a module, you can should use the `@Module` Annotation to list **all** your bindings. If you want your implementations be actual Singletons, then annotate your implementation classes with `@Singleton` else I dont see the point having a `HashMap` storing the instances.